# Constructors in Android Programming?

Tags: android, constructor

I have some values and want to pass with activity so that I can show in TextViews of Activity, I am unable to understand such a concept, so what should I do?
Simply I want to make constructor but unable to understand it that how will it be done, I am new to android programming, so needed help.

Comment: Searching for "Start activity with parameters" returns http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913592/start-an-activity-with-a-parameter among others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In android if you launched an activity there is a method called onCreate execute automatically.You can send values using Intent to the activity and can retrieve them in the Activity

Answer (score 3):

Start by reading the documentation at developer.android.com about intents and intent extras.

Answer (score 1):

The Activity (sub)class must have a default constructor without any parameters so that the system can instanciate it at run time.

To pass "parameters" to activities, you need to use the extra bundle of the intent.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
i.putExtra("com.sample.MyParameter", 666);
startActivity(i);
```

See [Starting An Activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#StartingAnActivity)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass one value then you can use intent but if you want to pass multiple values then using "Bundle" is best way.

```
Bundle bundel = new Bundle();
            bundel.putStringArray("key1",strings);
            bundel.putStringArray("key2",stringsofids);
            bundel.putString("key3", str31);
            bundel.putStringArray("key4",stringsbakup);
            bundel.putString("key5", str1);
            bundel.putString("key6", str4);
```