# Passing data through intent using Serializable

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I've implemented my class with serializable, but it still didn't work.

This is my class:

```
package com.ursabyte.thumbnail;

import java.io.Serializable;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;

public class Thumbnail implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String label = "";
    private Bitmap bitmap;

    public Thumbnail(String label, Bitmap bitmap) {
        this.label = label;
        this.bitmap = bitmap;
    }

    public void set_label(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public String get_label() {
        return this.label;
    }

    public void set_bitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        this.bitmap = bitmap;
    }

    public Bitmap get_bitmap(){
        return this.bitmap;
    }

    //  @Override
    //  public int compareTo(Thumbnail other) {
    //      if(this.label != null)
    //          return this.label.compareTo(other.get_label());
    //      else
    //          throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    //  }

}
```

This is what I want to be passing.

```
List<Thumbnail> all_thumbs = new ArrayList<Thumbnail>();
all_thumbs.add(new Thumbnail(string, bitmap));
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SomeClass.class);
intent.putExtra("value", all_thumbs);
```

But still it didn't work. I don't know how to use Parcelable, so I use this instead.

Comment: `Bitmap` class doesn't implement `Serializable`. You have to use `Parcelable` here. However, it's not a good idea to pass bitmaps using `Parcelable`...

Comment: what about byte array? does it implement Serializable?

Comment: yes, but be careful with large objects. Intent has a size limit for extras

Comment: or you can add transient before bitmap like this 
`private transient Bitmap bitmap;`

Answer (score 173):

Try to pass the serializable list using [Bundle.Serializable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putSerializable%28java.lang.String,%20java.io.Serializable%29):

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("value", all_thumbs);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

And in SomeClass Activity get it as:

```
Intent intent = this.getIntent();
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

List<Thumbnail> thumbs=
               (List<Thumbnail>)bundle.getSerializable("value");
```

Comment: I got this error : java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.ursabyte.thumbnail.Thumbnail)

Comment: @tegaralaga : see this example http://www.cnblogs.com/jsonxing/archive/2011/08/17/2143458.html

Comment: The problem is Bitmap class doesn't implement Serializabe like @vmironov said :)

Comment: @tegaralaga : yes i got it then Change Bitmap to image url and convert relevant image in next class instead of passing more bitmaps to other Activity

Comment: @tegaralaga : if this answer help in solving your current issue then mark it as answer.Thanks

Comment: Actually I convert it into byte array. Thanks for your concern, mate :)

Comment: As I understood the following line of your code needs to be changed to: bundle.putSerializable("value", all_thumbs.get(index));

Comment: I had to declare as ArrayList<~>, didn't like just List<~>

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK : How many Serializable Objects can we pass at one time through this bundle ?

Answer (score 15):

**This code may help you:**

```
public class EN implements Serializable {
//... you don't need implement any methods when you implements Serializable
}
```

**Putting data.** Create new Activity with extra:

```
EN enumb = new EN();
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("en", enumb); //second param is Serializable
startActivity(intent);
```

**Obtaining data** from new activity:

```
public class NewActivity extends Activity {

    private EN en;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        try {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            if (extras != null) {
                en = (EN)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("en"); //Obtaining data 
            }
//...
```

Comment: The object "en" is comming nullable

Answer (score 7):

I extended ρяσѕρєя K's answer to make the code full and workable. So, when you finish filling your 'all_thumbs' list, you should put its content one by one into the bundle and then into the intent:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

for (int i = 0; i<all_thumbs.size(); i++)
bundle.putSerializable("extras"+i, all_thumbs.get(i));

intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

In order to get the extras from the intent, you need:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
List<Thumbnail> thumbnailObjects = new ArrayList<Thumbnail>();

// collect your Thumbnail objects
for (String key : bundle.keySet()) {
thumbnailObjects.add((Thumbnail) bundle.getSerializable(key));
}

// for example, in order to get a value of the 3-rd object you need to:
String label = thumbnailObjects.get(2).get_label();
```

Advantage of `Serializable` is its simplicity. However, I would recommend you to consider using `Parcelable` method when you need transfer many data, because `Parcelable` is specifically designed for Android and it is more efficient than `Serializable`. You can create `Parcelable` class using:

1. an online tool - **[parcelabler](http://www.parcelabler.com/)**
2. a plugin for Android Studion - **[Android Parcelable code generator](http://corochann.com/fast-easy-parcelable-implementation-with-android-studio-parcelable-plugin-641.html)**

Answer (score 7):

Don't forget to **implement Serializable in every class your object will use** like a list of objects. Else your app will crash.

Example:

```
public class City implements Serializable {

private List<House> house;

public List<House> getHouse() {
    return house;
}

public void setHouse(List<House> house) {
    this.house = house;
}}
```

Then House needs to implements Serializable as so :

```
public class House implements Serializable {

private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}}
```

Then you can use:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("city", city);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

And retreive it with:

```
Intent intent = this.getIntent();
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
City city =  (City)bundle.getSerializable("city");
```

Comment: This is only part of a solution to a well received question. Can you elaborate please?

Comment: Say you have un object House and you need to Serializable a class City that has a List of houses.
You need to implement Serializable in the House class and the City Class

Comment: Please improve your answer by including at least a few more words to help explain it. Use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55929627/edit) button instead of adding a comment. [Comments](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) should be used for asking for more information or for suggesting improvements.

Answer (score 6):

**Sending Data:**

First make your serializable data by implement `Serializable` to your data class

```
public class YourDataClass implements Serializable {
String someText="Some text";
}
```

Then put it into intent

```
YourDataClass yourDataClass=new YourDataClass();
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ReceivingActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("value",yourDataClass);
startActivity(intent);
```

**Receiving Data:**

```
YourDataClass yourDataClass=(YourDataClass)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("value");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SomeClass.class);
intent.putExtra("value",all_thumbs);
startActivity(intent);
```

In SomeClass.java

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
if(b != null)
thumbs = (List<Thumbnail>) b.getSerializable("value");
```

Answer (score 3):

In **kotlin**:
Object class implements Serializable:

```
class MyClass: Serializable {
//members
}
```

At the point where the object sending:

```
val fragment = UserDetailFragment()
val bundle = Bundle()
bundle.putSerializable("key", myObject)
fragment.arguments = bundle
```

At the fragment, where we want to get our object:

```
val bundle: Bundle? = arguments
    bundle?.let {
        val myObject = it.getSerializable("key") as MyClass
        myObject.memberName?.let { it1 -> showShortToast(it1) }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a [Bundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) and then use [putSerializable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putSerializable%28java.lang.String,%20java.io.Serializable%29):

```
List<Thumbnail> all_thumbs = new ArrayList<Thumbnail>();
all_thumbs.add(new Thumbnail(string,bitmap));
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SomeClass.class);

Bundle extras = new Bundle();

extras.putSerializable("value",all_thumbs);
intent.putExtras(extras);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create your custom object and implement Serializable. Next, you can use `intent.putExtra("package.name.example", <your-serializable-object>)`.

In the second activity, you read it using `getIntent().getSerializableExtra("package.name.example")`

Otherwise, follow [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20java.io.Serializable%29) and [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) page.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following method when sending a `List<MySerializableObject>` via intent:

```
List<Thumbnail> thumbList = new ArrayList<>();
//Populate ...

Intent intent = new Intent(context, OtherClass.class);
intent.putExtra("ThumbArray", thumbList.toArray(new Thumbnail[0]));
//Send intent...
```

And retrieving it like so:

```
Thumbnail[] thumbArr = (Thumbnail[]) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("ThumbArray");
if (thumbArr != null) {
    List<Thumbnail> thumbList = Arrays.asList(thumbArr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1- You are using android.graphics.Bitmap which doesn't implements Serializable class so you have to remove that class then it will work.

2- for brief you can visit how to [pass data between intents](http://blogssolutions.co.in/android-pass-model-from-intents-using-serializable).

Answer (score 0):

If you're here because you did all of this and your app still crashes on switching activities:

My issues lied in my ParentClass using an object of another class in which I forgot to implement Serializable

```
public class A implements Serializable {
    
        private B[][] b;
    
}

public class B implements Serializable { //forgot this implementation

    B(){
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass a list, first implements Serializable in your class.

Then you must cast your list to serializable

```
val bundle = Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("list", list as Serializable)
```

To get list in others activity or fragment

```
val intent = this.getIntent()
val bundle = intent.getExtras()
val thumbs: List<Thumbnail> = bundle.getSerializable("list") as List<Thumbnail>
```