# Is it possible serialize a class that contains attributes like usbManager and usbDevice?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, usb

I have this class that I use to configure the Usb connection with a external device. It works ok on my activity android, but I would like to pass it to another activity, but I'm not able to do that. I'm trying to serialize the class to pass to another activity but when I call startactivity the other activity comes a exception.

This is when I call the activity:

```
Intent lights = new Intent(this, Screen2Activity.class);
lights.putExtra("usb", usb);
startActivity(lights);
```

The exception is:
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable 
    object (name = com.example.vcontrol.Usb)

This is my class:

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------
//
// Class that configures and communicates with the Usb Port
//
//-----------------------------------------------------------

public class Usb implements Serializable {

//USB Parameters and Controls
private UsbManager usbManager = null;
private UsbDeviceConnection conn = null;
private UsbDevice device = null;
private UsbInterface usbIf = null;
private UsbEndpoint epIN = null;
private UsbEndpoint epOUT = null;
...
```

Somebody can help me?

Answer (score 0):

yes, only if they are Serializable, if you don't control the class then you're out of luck.

Comment: I need to know if this elements (Usbmanager and usbDevice) can be serialized! :)

Answer (score 0):

Q: Very important question ... ?? What exactly is the exception ??

My guess is `java.IO.NotSerializableException`.

If so, you basically have two choices:

1) Modify your class so that it implements Serializable

... or ...

2) Extend your class, and have the new subclass implement Serializable.

Here are more details:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html

http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaSerialization/article.html

============   ADDENDUM   ============

Thank you for your update!  I believe this is the solution

> [Passing data through intent using Serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14333449/passing-data-through-intent-using-serializable)
>
> ```
> // Example "serialize"
> Bundle bundle = new Bundle();  
> bundle.putSerializable("value", all_thumbs);
> intent.putExtras(bundle);
>
> // Example "deserialize"
> Intent intent=this.getIntent();
> Bundle bundle=intent.getExtras();
>
> List<Thumbnail> thumbs=
>                (List<Thumbnail>)bundle.getSerializable("value");
> ```

Comment: Ok! Thanks. One doubt... To serialize a class Do I need only put the  "implements Serializable" in my class? I've just made this!