# Data passing between fragment activity to another activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, dictionary, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I want to send my location(address) from my fragment activity to another activity and show the address there. I tried for last couple days but not failed every time. please  guide me.

Comment: "I tried for last couple days but not failed every time" - what have you tried specifically?

Comment: Check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343241/passing-data-between-a-fragment-and-its-container-activity

Answer (score 0):

Use `Intent` to pass data from one activity to another

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(FirstActivity.java,SecondActivity.class);
myIntent.putExtra("data","**** Your data *****");
startActivity(myIntent);
```

If you want to pass user derfined Object from one activity to another then you have to implement `Serilizable` or `Parcelable`

Check the following links for how to use `Serilizable`

[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14333449/passing-data-through-intent-using-serializable) & [link2](http://shri.blog.kraya.co.uk/2010/04/26/android-parcel-data-to-pass-between-activities-using-parcelable-classes/)

Comment: but its not normal data passing from one activity to another activity. It's fragment to activity.

Comment: Yeah you can pass data from `FragmentActivity` to normal `Activity` same way as you do in Activity to Activity

Comment: It will be more clear what you want to do if you post some of your `code'

Comment: As I said in my question as well, I want to pass my location data (or any other string for example "123" from my mapfragment to a.activity). Hope it will clear your confusion

Comment: @user3277750: do u want to pass data on click of marker in mapfragment?

Comment: it does not matter to pass data on marker click or by another way as long as it passes data.

Comment: allright then the answers is same via Intent no matter a fragmentActivity or activity

Answer (score 0):

use getActivity() to send data into other activity

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(),SecondActivity.class);
myIntent.putExtra("key","**** Your data *****");
getActivity().startActivity(myIntent);
```