# Android Intents, how to pass and receive an InetAddress?

Tags: android, android-intent, datagram, inetaddress

I have the following line of code

```
intent.putExtra("connectionAddress", connectionManager.connectionAddress);
```

`connectionAddress` is in fact an `InetAddress`. I cannot figure out the appropriate method to '`get..`' this. I suspect I need to cast it to another type and back again? In which case what would be the best approach?

I need to ensure I still have the information needed to create a `DatagramSocket` in the next activity.

Comment: Since `InetAddress` implements Serializable, you could just use a serializable-extra: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14333555/865900

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the address from the intent as a serializable extra, then cast it back to `InetAddress`.

```
InetAddress address = (InetAddress)intent.getSerializableExtra("connectionAddress");
```