# Pass 3D-array to Activity in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, multidimensional-array

I am trying to pass a 3D-doublearray to another activity. I don know why I get NullpointerException? What is missing?

MainActivity

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, DataActivity.class);
 Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
 mBundle.putSerializable("list", output_data);
 intent.putExtras(mBundle);
 startActivity(intent);
```

DataActivity (reveiver)

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
 double[][][] params = (double[][][]) intent.getExtras().getSerializable("list");
```

And I know for certain that the 3d-array already is allocated in the MainActivity. I have tested that!

Would be glad if someone has any solution to this and could answer why I get a NullPointerException.

*(Edit: NullpointerException at the line double[][][] params = ...)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure `double[][][]` doesn't implement `Serializable`. What you can do is make your own class like so:

```
public class MyArrayWrapper implements Serializable {

  private double[][][] arr;

  public MyArrayWrapper(double[][][] value) {
    arr = value;
  }

  public double[][][] getArray() {
    return arr;
  }
}
```

You then instantiate that wrapper class and put it as a serializable instead. Then when getting the serializable you do it like this:

```
MyArrayWrapper wrap = (MyArrayWrapper) intent.getExtras().getSerializable("list");
double[][]][] myArray = wrap.getArray();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks will try this out tomorrow after som sleep and may accept then :-)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need a class that implements serializable?

[Passing data through intent using Serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14333449/passing-data-through-intent-using-serializable)

In this example, they are using custom class and List<> to serialize in a bundle. You can create a class with the 3D array inside?