# Serialized Intent Extras seem empty after starting new Activity

Tags: java, android

So i've benn working on App which needs a BlockingQueue to communicate between the UI Thread and a handler thread. So i createt a LinkedBlockingQueue and the Thread in the onCreate of my first Activity.

```
BlockingQueue<String> UIqueueRx = new LinkedBlockingDeque<String>();
BlockingQueue<String> UIqueueTx = new LinkedBlockingDeque<String>();

final main m = new main(UIqueueRx,UIqueueTx);
Thread myMainThread = new Thread(m);
myMainThread.setName("AdapterThread");
myMainThread.start();
```

I need the BlockingQueue also during the next Actyvities, so put them into the     Intent.putExtra and startet next Activity.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(),Start.class);
myIntent.putExtra("UIqueueRx",(Serializable) UIqueueRx);
myIntent.putExtra("UIqueueTx",(Serializable) UIqueueTx);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

So in my new Actyvity i wanted to take the BlockingQueue fron the Intent and bind it to my local class.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);
    BlockingQueue<String> UIqueueRx = (BlockingQueue<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("UIqueueRx");
    BlockingQueue<String> UIqueueTx = (BlockingQueue<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("UIqueueTx");
    //...
}
```

But if i later use the Queue to send Strings to the Thread nothing hapens, the String stays in Queue. So i tried to debug and mentions the id number of the Queues changed so they arent connected anymore. I also checked the Intent itself, after open the new activity there are no Extras anymore.

Anyone mention a mistake i overlooked? 
Is this kind of code even rational or is there a spimler way?

Comment: Any reason you don't use either a service or fragments with a main activity which holds your background thread?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14333555/833647

Comment: @KenWolf Tried this before same problem...

Answer (score 0):

The `onCreate()` method only gets called once when the Activity is created. If its paused, resumed or restarted later on it skips the onCreate Method.

[image: http://developer.android.com/images/activity_lifecycle.png]

If you want to persist the Extras from the Intent, you should use class fields.