# How I can pass class object between two activities?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent, android-inflate

I have a class `Books.java` that `implements` a list of `Book.java`, and in `MainActivity.java` i fill the object library with books. I want send the object library from `MainActivity.java` to `ListActivity.java` but not works with `i.putExtra.` How I can do it?

Books.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Books implements DataAggregate <Book>{
private List<Book> books;

public Books(){};

public List<Book> getAll() {
    return this.getBooks();
}

public int size() {
    return this.getBooks().size();
}

public void insert(Book element) {
    this.getBooks().add(element);
}

public void delete(Book element) {
    this.getBooks().remove(element);
}

private List<Book> getBooks() {
    if (books==null){
        books=new ArrayList<Book>();
    }
    return books;
}
```

}

MainActivity.java

```
Books library;
for (int i = 0; i<db_books.size(); i++){
       String name = db_books.get(i).getBookName();
       String author = db_books.get(i).getBookAuthor();
       String epc = db_books.get(i).getBookEpc();
       Integer number = db_books.get(i).getNumBooks();
       Book myBook = new Book(name, author, epc, number);
       library.insert(myBook);
}
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ListActivity.class);
i.putExtra("library",library);
startActivity(i);
```

ListActivity.java

```
Books library = extras.getString("library");
```

Book.java

```
public class Book implements Serializable {

    private String bookName;
    private String bookAuthor;
    private String bookEpc;
    private Integer numBooks;


    public Book(){

    }

    public Book(String bname, String bauthor, String bepc, Integer nbooks){
        this.bookName = bname;
        this.bookAuthor = bauthor;
        this.bookEpc = bepc;
        this.numBooks = nbooks;
    }

    public String getBookName() {
        return bookName;
    }

    public void setBookName(String bookName) {
        this.bookName = bookName;
    }

    public String getBookAuthor() {
        return bookAuthor;
    }

    public void setBookAuthor(String bookAuthor) {
        this.bookAuthor = bookAuthor;
    }

    public String getBookEpc() {
        return bookEpc;
    }

    public void setBookEpc(String bookEpc) {
        this.bookEpc = bookEpc;
    }

    public Integer getNumBooks() {
        return numBooks;
    }

    public void setNumBooks(Integer numBooks) {
        this.numBooks = numBooks;
    }

    public void prettyPrint(){

        Log.d("Book:", this.bookName+" "+this.bookAuthor+" "+this.bookEpc+" "+this.numBooks.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14333555/2078074). Hope it helps for you.

Comment: @Lawrance I have to implement Books.java as Serializable?

Comment: @Lawrance not works, `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{upf.mybooks/upf.mybooks.ListActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: upf.mybooks.model.Books cannot be cast to java.util.List`

Answer (score 0):

Try this may be help to you

**send like this**

```
 Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DetailedBookActivity.class);
 i.putExtra("library",library);
```

**and get like this**

```
Book libs= new Book();
libs = (Book)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("library");
```

Comment: this not works, `i.putExtra("library", (Serializable) library);`

Comment: It gives a ERROR `FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                             Process: upf.mybooks, PID: 27029
                                                             java.lang.ClassCastException: upf.mybooks.model.Books cannot be cast to java.io.Serializable`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
Books library = extras.getString("library");
```

You should do

```
Books library = (Books) extras. getSerializableExtra("library");
```

Comment: That not works, `FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                             Process: upf.mybooks, PID: 30008
                                                             java.lang.ClassCastException: upf.mybooks.model.Books cannot be cast to java.io.Serializable`

Answer (score 0):

I solved in this way:

To pass between two activities I use this,

In MainActivity.java:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ListActivity.class);
Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("library", library);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

In ListActivity.java to caputre the library:

```
Intent intent=this.getIntent();
Bundle bundle=intent.getExtras();
final Books library =(Books)bundle.getSerializable("library");
```

Final library object in ListActivity.java has all books.

Answer (score 0):

Books class have to implements Serializable

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Books implements DataAggregate <Book>, Serializable {
    private List<Book> books;

    public Books(){};

    public List<Book> getAll() {
    return this.getBooks();
    }

    public int size() {
        return this.getBooks().size();
    }

    public void insert(Book element) {
        this.getBooks().add(element);
    }

    public void delete(Book element) {
        this.getBooks().remove(element);
    }

    private List<Book> getBooks() {
        if (books==null){
            books=new ArrayList<Book>();
        }
        return books;
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
Books library;
for (int i = 0; i<db_books.size(); i++){
   String name = db_books.get(i).getBookName();
   String author = db_books.get(i).getBookAuthor();
   String epc = db_books.get(i).getBookEpc();
   Integer number = db_books.get(i).getNumBooks();
   Book myBook = new Book(name, author, epc, number);
   library.insert(myBook);
}
// don't use applicationContext. use activity context "this".
Intent i = new Intent(this, ListActivity.class);
i.putExtra("library", library);
startActivity(i);
```

and ListActivity getIntent

```
Books library = (Books) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("library");
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion first you should use Parcelable. For more details refer below links.

[Link1](http://www.3pillarglobal.com/insights/parcelable-vs-java-serialization-in-android-app-development)

[Link2](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2015/05/android-parcelable-tutorial-list-class-2.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
first your Books class implements to Serializable.


 Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ListActivity.class);
 i.putExtra("library",library);
startActivity(i);

get method 

Intent i = getIntent();
Book libs= new Book();
libs = (Book) i.getSerializableExtra("library");
```