# Pass custom array list of objects

Tags: java, android

I am trying to pass a custom ArrayList of objects between activites. I keep getting wrong argument errors. Read around on exisitng questions but none of them could resolve the issue.

Could you please point me in the right direction?

CODE BREAKDOWN:

```
public class object1 implements parcelable{
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    //things that need to be written

    }
    public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
        public MoodEvent createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new MoodEvent(in);
        }

        public MoodEvent[] newArray(int size) {
            return new MoodEvent[size];
        }
    };
public class list1{  //** "implements Parceblable" gives error**
      private ArrayList<object1> ArrayList1, ArrayList2; //** Filters used on **ArrayList2
      public void writeToParcel(Parcel out) {
        out.writeTypedList(ArrayList1);
    }


    public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
        public MoodEvent createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new MoodEvent(in);
        }

        public MoodEvent[] newArray(int size) {
            return new MoodEvent[size];
        }
    };
}

public class someActivity {
.
.
.
mapIntent = new Intent(oldActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

bundle.putParcelableArrayList(moodEventList);   //**wrong argument types on both lines**
mapIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("mylist",moodEventList);
.
.
.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`putParcelableArrayList` will expect an ArrayList containing objects that implement the `Parcelable` interface.
Assuming your object1 class correctly implements this, you can use just a regular `ArrayList<object1>` instance and you don't need the custom `list1` class.

If you really want to though, and your `list1` class also implements the interface, you can use the `putParcelable` method, since your list is just a single parcelable now.

Comment: list1 was needed for sure. Going with 'putparcelable' definitely fixed the problem, given you have all the correct parcel methods in your object and list1 class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public class YOUR_CLASS_NAME implements Serializable
```

[Passing data through intent using Serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14333449/passing-data-through-intent-using-serializable)

Answer (score 0):

> You can try the following code to send and receive custom arraylist of
>   objects from one activity to another.

### Send Intent Values:

> You can try the follwing code to send parsable arraylist with intent.

```
 private List<ResourceTypeList> mResourceList;
 public void sendParcableIntent()
 {
    Intent i=new Intent(ResourcePhoneBook.this,ResourceSort.class);
    Bundle toSend = new Bundle();
    toSend.putParcelableArrayList("Data", (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>)mResourceList);
    i.putExtras(toSend);
    startActivity(i);
 }
```

### Receive Intent Values:

> You can get parcelable arraylist with normal ArrayList format.

```
ArrayList mArraylist1;
Bundle bdl = getIntent().getExtras();
mArraylist1 = bdl.getParcelableArrayList("Data");
```

### parcelable model class:

```
public class ResourceTypeList implements Parcelable {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("resource_type")
    @Expose
    private String resourceType;

    /**
     *
     * @return
     *     The id
     */
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param id
     *     The id
     */
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     *     The resourceType
     */
    public String getResourceType() {
        return resourceType;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param resourceType
     *     The resource_type
     */
    public void setResourceType(String resourceType) {
        this.resourceType = resourceType;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(resourceType);
        dest.writeInt(id);

    }

   public ResourceTypeList(String resourceType) {
       this.resourceType = resourceType;

   }
   protected ResourceTypeList(Parcel in) {
       resourceType = in.readString();
       id= in.readInt();

   }
    public static final Creator<ResourceTypeList> CREATOR = new Creator<ResourceTypeList>() {
        @Override
        public ResourceTypeList createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new ResourceTypeList(source);
        }

        @Override
        public ResourceTypeList[] newArray(int size) {
            return new ResourceTypeList[size];
        }
    };
}
```