# I'm trying to get an array and cast an intent but program keeps crashing

Tags: java, android

I'm doing a project. I have a couple of classes: Course, Instructor, Student. The Course class doesn't contain any arrays in it but the Instructor class contains an array of type Course

```
public class Instructor {

  static private int ID = 0;
  static private int nofi = 0;
  private String FName, title, LName;
  private Course[] c1;

  public Instructor(String t, String fn, String ln, Course[] c1_1, int noc)
  {
      title = t;
      FName = fn;
      LName = ln;
      //ID += 1;
      nofi = 0;
      c1 = new Course[noc];
      c1 = c1_1.clone();

  }

  public String getFName()
  {
      return FName;
  }
  public String getLName()
  {
      return LName;
  }
  public String getTitle()
  {
      return title;
  }
  public int getID()
  {
      return ID;
  }
  public Course[] getC1()
  {
      return c1;
  }
  public int getNofi()
  {
      return ++nofi;
  }

}
```

I'm trying to use the `getC1` method which is an array of type `Course`.

What I did in my main activity is that I made an array object of type `Instructor` and I used Intent Serializable inside a list to send the whole array of Instructor to my Second Activity

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {
        if (position == 1)
        {
            intent.putExtra("instructor class", (Serializable)i);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }
});
```

And in my SecondActivity I receive it in this way:

```
Intent intent2 = getIntent();
Instructor x[];
x = (Instructor[])intent2.getSerializableExtra("instructor class");
x[0].getC1();
```

But when I try to run the app, it crashes right away at

```
x[0].getC1();
```

it tells me `Attempt to read from a null array`.

However I removed all the nulls from my code and its fine. I don't know how to solve this or if the Syntax is right or wrong. How can I return an array?

The error message:

```
04-10 15:48:36.684 26089-26089/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
04-10 15:48:36.816 26089-26089/com.example.saa0d.kuattend W/System:                                       ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.saa0d.kuattend-         1/lib/arm64
04-10 15:48:36.873 26089-26089/com.example.saa0d.kuattend W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
04-10 15:48:36.957 26089-26089/com.example.saa0d.kuattend D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-10 15:48:36.958 26089-26089/com.example.saa0d.kuattend E/AndroidRuntime: 
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.saa0d.kuattend, PID: 26089
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.saa0d.kuattend/com.example.saa0d.kuattend.SecondActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from null array
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2666)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2727)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1478)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from null array
    at com.example.saa0d.kuattend.SecondActivity.onCreate(SecondActivity.java:27)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6682)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2619)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2727) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1478) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
```

This is the error message in the android studio:

[image: This is the error message in the android studio]

Comment: add your stacktrace

Comment: what do you mean by stack trace?

Comment: the error you are getting when the app crashes

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

implement serializable

```
 public class Instructor implements Serializable
  {
  }
```

you pass Instructor class object to next activity not array of Instructor class

```
    x = (Instructor[])intent2.getSerializableExtra("instructor class");
```

change to

```
    x = (Instructor)intent2.getSerializableExtra("instructor class");
```

one more thing use key without any space like this

```
"instructor_class"
```

Comment: I changed it to that but I'm still getting the same problem. "Attempt to read from a null array"

Comment: I did that. Im getting a message of incompatible types. Required: com.example.saa0d.kuattend.Instructor[] Found: com.example.saa0d.kuattend.instructor

Comment: intent.putExtra("instructor class", (Serializable)i);

post exactly what is i?

Comment: i is the variable of type Instructor. it's an array

Answer (score 0):

You should make your classes implement [Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) and after that use intent.putParcelableArray("instructor class", i); 
Parcelable is faster than Serializable

Another way is to keep using Serializable and try to replace Instructor[] to ArrayList, but I'm not sure this will help

Comment: what is the difference? My teacher has told me to use Serializable because it can transfer everything in one fell swoop.

Comment: Serializable uses Reflection and it's much slower. Nevertheless have you tried to make Course class implement Serializable?

Comment: Try to use Bundle with ArrayList as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14333555/7027883

Answer (score 0):

@Hitesh Gehlot
thank you man

```
       x = (Instructor)intent2.getSerializableExtra("instructor class");
```

This was part of the problem, it shouldn't be an array.
The main problem was that when I come to run the app, my debugged was set to run the SecondActivity only without the main one. So nothing was passed thats why it was null.