# How to implement Serializable using toggle button in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, pass-by-value, serializable

I've created a toggle button in my cardView and when the toggle button is pressed it should copy the cardItem to another fragment. I've done this for toggleButton:

```
 holder.favButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton favButton, boolean isChecked){
                if (isChecked)
                    favButton.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(favButton.getContext(),R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
                Intent intent = new Intent(context,FavouriteFragment.class);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putSerializable("DATA", (Serializable) cardItems);
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                context.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
```

and this is where  i want to retrieve the values that I've put.

```
private void initializeCardItemList(){
        CardItemModel cardItemModel;
        String[] cardTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.fav_cards);
        String[] cardContents = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.fav_cards_content);
        final int length = cardTitles.length;
        for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
            cardItemModel = new CardItemModel(cardTitles[i],cardContents[i]);
            cardItems.add(cardItemModel);
        }
    }
```

With what I should replace this to initialize the cardItems? (* only showing cards in which toogle button is pressed)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to know how to pass Serializable data to another fragment through intent?
If so, it will help you
[Passing data through intent using Serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14333449/passing-data-through-intent-using-serializable)

If not, please let me know in detail. thank you.

Comment: i've already checked that. i wanted to know how to initialize card items.

Comment: Do you mean how to initialize card items "in another fragment" where you sent data to? I think it doesn't need to initialize card items in another fragment and just you need to write **Intent intent = this.getIntent(); Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras(); List<CardItemModel> cardItems = (List<CardItemModel>)bundle.getSerializable("DATA");**.