# Android: Pass serialisable object data to another activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, kotlin

I have a class, which contains an array list of another object, when I try to pass the data to another activity, it does not pass other objects like my array list Appointment, how to do? Here are my classes:

```
open class Customer(var name: String = "") : Serializable{
    var appointments: List<Appointment>? = null
}
```

And:

```
class Appointment(val id: String?, val title: String?, val date: Date) : Serializable { 
}
```

To pass data:

```
putExtra("customer", customer)
```

To get data:

```
intent.getSerializableExtra("customer") as Customer?
```

It works, but the list of appointments is not sent, only the customer, why?

The list is not null before doing the startActivity, but when I do the getIntent I get the null list, it was not sent

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing data through intent using Serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14333449/passing-data-through-intent-using-serializable)

Comment: No, because I want to pass my object, and all the objects that are in it

Answer (score 0):

`List` doesn't implement `Serializable`.

How about try to use `Arraylist`.