# parceling an enum via an intent

Tags: android, kotlin

I've a problem with parceling an enum type via an intent, problem is with this line. `intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra` and the error is

> not enough information to infer information for type variable T

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, persistentState: PersistableBundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState)
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)

    if (savedInstanceState == null)
        (fragment as DataFragment).setData(intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Application.BUNDLE_DATA) as ArrayList<DataEnum>)
}
```

**Enum**

```
@Parcelize
enum class DataEnum : Parcelable {

    Foo { override fun toString() = "Foo" },
    Bar { override fun toString() = "Bar" },
    Baz { override fun toString() = "Baz" };

    companion object {
        private fun list(): ArrayList<DataEnum> {
            return arrayListOf(
                FOO,
                BAR,
                BAZ
            )
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: 1.) your `setData` will probably not work, you are supposed to be using `setArguments` before you add a fragment with a fragment transaction and 2.) why not just use `putSerializable`

Comment: sorry didn't get you, I'm in an activity, setting data to a fragment, hope this helps

Comment: Exactly, a Fragment should be getting its data through `setArguments`.

Comment: Thanks I understood you at `Activity to Fragment` communication advise via `setArguments` and I appreciate it, but problem here now is `activity to activity`, I could send the data from `ActivityA` via `putParcelableArrayListExtra` but I can't `getParcelableArrayListExtra` in `activityB`. Hope it's clear.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Enum

`Enum extends Serializable`

so use

`Intent.putSerializable` and `Intent.getSerializable`

and it'll all work out

Comment: Thanks Blundell, just for the sake of the argument can you please provide a parcelable example while keeping this serializable answer intact. Because I read it's faster and I just want to keep everything parcelable across the app. Please also read my last comment about the issue, I can `putParcelableArrayListExtra` in activityA but can't `getParcelableArrayListExtra` in activityB due to compilation error.

Comment: you mean `Bundle.putSerializable`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14333449/passing-data-through-intent-using-serializable

Comment: Yes Bundle sorry :-) FYI "Parceleable is faster than Serializable" I wouldn't worry about that at all, it's nanoseconds unless you have huge objects that are constantly being parceled. Get it working, then optimize for performance if you have to (which I bet you won;t)