# Does Android RelativeLayout LayoutParams can set R.id ?

Tags: android, android-activity, layoutparams

In my app, I create the gridview and then add the view by RelativeLayout LayoutParams.
But how can i call it in another activity?
such as gridview looping the 10 article and hide the icon, i create the edit button to control hide/show the icon. but i dont know how to call it.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you should show some code.  You can't add a view by adding RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.  ...and a View does not persist across activities.  ...and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. because the coding too large so i can't just show here. But in my issue is i just want to get the id of imageview with tag in another activity.

Answer (score 0):

Once you switch activities, I don't think you can directly access the ui elements of the previous activity. You should try to send data between activities by creating intents with arguments like this :

[Start an Activity with a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913592/start-an-activity-with-a-parameter)

If you from activity A to B and you want to pass data back to A, launch A with an intent that has the extra data you need.

Parse the data from the intent and update your UI accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I use the static value for solved this. Thanks.