# key1 cannot be resolved to a variable?

Tags: java, android, string, key-value

Apparently having some issues with my Key-Value the way it is currently set up. The goal is to read the value of a Spinner (set using a string array) and then based on it open up a specific local html file.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Button btnGo;

    String pageChoice;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final Spinner page = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.txtPage);
        final SharedPreferences sharedPref =PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        btnGo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnGo);
        btnGo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                pageChoice = page.getSelectedItem().toString();

                //Hopefully will allow for "global" url setting.
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                editor.putString("key1", pageChoice);
                editor.commit();
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Web.class));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The error is located in my Web.java.

```
public class Web extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.web);
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String strPage = sharedPref.getString(key1, "");

        if (strPage = "By The Numbers") {
            //WebView
            WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);
            WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
            webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/2.html");
        } else if (strPage = "Photos") {
            //WebView
            WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);
            WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
            webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/3.html");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Also, is there an issue with my strPage being a String? How would I change it over to working with an If/Else instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make double quotes around key1

```
 String strPage = sharedPref.getString("key1", "");
```

because it is not a variable. It is a string.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! That fixed the first problem. How would I go about making it so that the value output is a variable? I'm honestly just getting started with Android development and I may have bit off more than I can chew with this one. xP

Comment: @JoeySides Sorry i can't get you. Would you like to define the key1 as a variable string? to get something from the `sharedPref`?

Comment: Basically, what I'm trying to do is determine which item is selected from the String Array on my MainActivity and use that with nested "if/if else" statements to change which URL is used for the WebView. I guess in other words, I'm trying to determine the position of the Spinner.

Comment: @JoeySides Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913592/start-an-activity-with-a-parameter) thread. You can put the value in the Intent ang get it in the new started activity.

Answer (score 1):

```
 String strPage = sharedPref.getString("key1", "");
```