# Android App, checkbox search engine

Tags: java, android, search-engine

I am creating an app in Android Studio and I am fairly new to java programming. The main idea is that in the main activity of my project I will have a list of different options, with check-boxes next to them.

A user has to click on check-boxes which interest him and then press the button on the bottom "Search". After that a new activity will show and for example if the user picked "Option A" and  "Option D" then in the new activity two images will show which I will assign to these two activities.

I am can't figure out a way to actually show these images as a result of the checkboxes selected by the user.

Can someone give me a tip on how it may be possible to do?

Comment: what have you tried and where do you fail? please read  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Check this post : http://stackoverflow.com/a/3913720/2940964

Answer (score 0):

You should start learning Java ASAP (also Android basics). I'd recommend learning it, before developing even simplest app.

---

You can store options in a list. First declare list:

```
List<String> optionList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then, as user checks checkboxes you can add options:

```
optionList.add("Option A");
// Or whatever the option is
```

When you start new activity, you can put&send some data:

```
void openNewActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("options", optionList);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

From within NewActivity's OnCreate method, you can get data:

```
List<String> options = getIntent().getSerializableExtra("options");
```

Voila!

---

**Good luck!**

Answer (score 0):

You have to know Inents,Activity,Images,CheckBoxes. Please search on the web, After that it is also hard I will implement for you.But right know I will suggest you next one.
1)Learn Activity and How to pass through multiple activity data.
2)How to use Checkbox and How to set Image to ImageView .