# DroidEdit Termux integration

Tags: javascript, android, bash, termux

DroidEdit allows you to run commands if you have sl4a installed and the am command works wonderfully... I was wondering if there is a way to use am to launch an app with params .. specifically I want a command that will tell termux to run a command on a file that I specificy ... so far I found this snippet that launches the termux app .. now how do I get it to run node or webpack from npm as well?

> am start --user 0 -n com.termux/com.termux.app.TermuxActivity

Comment: If you are root you can run the executable from param. I am not an Android expert. But i think this may help you if you are a expert on this field https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913592/start-an-activity-with-a-parameter

Comment: Thank you, it has indeed given me some insight on how intent's work.

Comment: A bit late, but if you have tasker installed, as well as termux:tasker, you can create an intent listener in tasker easily, and have that trigger a any script you want in termux:tasker. Both are well documented, and can be found with a Google search for both "tasker" and "termux:tasker". Also Google "sent intent to tasker" for a shortcut. Hope this helps!