# Trying to open activity from within onClick event in my adapter

Tags: android, android-activity, adapter

I am trying to learn how to open an activity from a click event inside my adapter.

Right now, I can click a cardview item and send a textview content to a toast thanks to jogarcia, but i cant seem to figure out how to open a new activity and pass the textview content through putExtra()

Here is my adapter code:...

```java
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final ListItem ListItem = ListItems.get(position);
        holder.ConfinedSpaceID.setText(ListItem.getSpaceId());
        holder.ConfinedSpaceDescription.setText(ListItem.getDescription());
//the following is added to create an onclick listener for the cardview
        holder.cardview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String string;
                string = ListItem.getSpaceId().toString();
                Toast.makeText(context, "You clicked "+string, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

I want to be able to open a new activity called DisplayIndividual.class, and pass 'string' as a putExtra().  Any help would be appreciated

Comment: use Intent.....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Start an Activity with a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913592/start-an-activity-with-a-parameter)

Comment: Please search you problem, before posting here.

Comment: For reference: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters

Answer (score 0):

You can pass context from your activity class to adapter like this

```
AdapterClass obj = new AdapterClass(this);
```

In Adapter class

```
Context context; //global
public AdapterClass(Context context)
{
   this.context = context;  
}
```

Then you can use `Intent` now

```
@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String string;
                string = ListItem.getSpaceId().toString();
                Toast.makeText(context, "You clicked "+string, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(context,...)
            }
        });
```

Comment: thanks John Joe  -  The adapter class content is straight forward, but where do I add 'AdapterClass obj = new AdapterClass(this);'

Comment: The AdapterClass is your adapter class's name

Answer (score 0):

Put an int which is your id into the new Intent.

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(
     FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
final Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("key", "value");
intent.putExtras(b);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a basically question in Android.
We usually pass data from activity to another through [Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent).

lets make some change from your snippet:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final ListItem ListItem = ListItems.get(position);
    holder.ConfinedSpaceID.setText(ListItem.getSpaceId());
    holder.ConfinedSpaceDescription.setText(ListItem.getDescription());

    //the following is added to create an onclick listener for the cardview
    holder.cardview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String string;
            string = ListItem.getSpaceId().toString();
            Toast.makeText(context, "You clicked "+string, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            // code here, context usually is which activity you set this adapter from
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, DisplayIndi​​vidual.class);
            intent.putExtra("stringKey", string);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

and in `DisplayIndi​​vidual`:

you can get the string data back from Intent

```
String string getIntent().getStringExtra("stringKey");
```

Comment: Thank you all for the quick responses...   my evening is late, but I will try your suggestions tomorrow.  To those in my time zone... sleep well,  to those elswhere... good day  :)

Comment: Hello Hababa...   I tried your code and got an error on DisplayIndividual.class as well as startActivity(intent).

Comment: maybe I can give some advise if you can paste some error log here

Comment: It is fine.  I was able to make it work using getContext()

Comment: Oh my fault .. I thought your adapter was defined in activity as an inner class ..
BTW, `startActivity()` is the member function of `Context`, you can call it  straightforward with `context.startActivity()` instead of additional `getContext().startActivity()`, though they are the same ..
Anyway, glad you solved your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

In onClick method :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        context.startActivity(intent);
```

and in fragment pass the context :

```
adapter = new Adapter(list , this.getApplicationContext());
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all so much for your input.  It has been wonderful.  The following worked perfectly for me :)   I hadn't read/learned enough to understand getContext()

```
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(),DisplayIndividual.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("STRING_2_Search", string);
                v.getContext().startActivity(myIntent);
```