# Pass the values to another activity in Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-intent, android-activity

The MainActivity.kt recieve the latitude and longtitude

```
val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity,MapsActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("latitude", latitude)
        intent.putExtra("longitude", longitude)
```

And then pass to MapsActivity.kt

```
val intent = Intent(this@MapsActivity,MainActivity::class.java)
    val lat=intent.getStringExtra("latitude").toDouble()
    val lon=intent.getStringExtra("longtitude").toDouble()
```

And when I run the application I get a errors while I go to MapsActivity
[image]
[image]
[image]

What is the main cause of this problem and how can I pass the values in the correct way?

Comment: You create a second `Intent` object and expect to retrieve data from the first with it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913592/start-an-activity-with-a-parameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set

```
val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity,MapsActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra("latitude", latitude!!)
intent.putExtra("longitude", longitude!!)
startActivity(intent)
```

Get

```
var bundle :Bundle ?=intent.extras
var latitude = bundle!!.getString("latitude").toDouble()
var longitude = bundle!!.getString("longitude").toDouble()
```